# Something went wrong with my code

Tags: c, fault

I was trying something, but the Programm will crash with this Error: Segmentation fault: 11
Has somebody a solution?

```
char str1[20]

printf("Enter Data: ");
scanf("%s", &str1);


printf("Entered Data: %s\n", str1);
int ex = strtod(str1, sizeof(str1));
printf("%s\n", ex);
if (ex == "1")
{
    printf("1 Detected");
}
```

.. and it won't detect the number 1 if 1 was provided..

Comment: This program won't compile. If you typed in the program, don't do that; please copy and paste it instead.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Oh it would compile all right, but the compiler would be shouting warnings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Hmm, without `main` and a function body, I doubt it will compiler without errors.

Comment: `if (ex == "1")` does not work.

Comment: Yeah, i know. But how can i do it better?

Comment: (1) Compile with options `-Wall` and `-Wextra`
(2) Use GDB
(3) Profit

Comment: What happens if someone enters a string with more that 19 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here.

This:

```
scanf("%s", &str1);
```

Should be:

```
scanf("%s", str1);
```

The `%s` format specifier expects a `char *`, but you are passing it a `char **`.

Then there's this:

```
int ex = strtod(str1, sizeof(str1));
```

The `strtod` function expects a `char **` for the second argument, which is the address of a `char *` which will point to the first character that fails to parse as a double.  Also, you're assigning the result (a `double`) to an `int`.

You probably want to use the similar function `strtol` instead, which is for parsing integers:

```
int ex = strtol(str1, NULL, 10);
```

This is also incorrect:

```
printf("%s\n", ex);
```

Like `scanf`, `%s` in `printf` expects a `char *`, not an `int`.  Use `%d` instead.  This is the most likely cause of the crash.

Finally there's this:

```
if (ex == "1")
```

That's not how you perform integer comparison.  You're instead comparing `ex` against the address of a string constant.  Do this instead:

```
if (ex == 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The major problems are in these three lines:

```
int ex = strtod(str1, sizeof(str1));
printf("%s\n", ex);
if (ex == "1")
```

The first convert a string to `double` value, which you then convert to an integer. That's okay, but you should probably be using [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) if you wanted an integer value.

The second and third line however are very flawed. In the second line you treat the integer as a *pointer*, namely a pointer to a character, a.k.a. a string. The integer value is not a pointer, treating it as a string will lead to *undefined behavior*, and it's probably here you have your crash.

Then the third line, it's not technically invalid but it will just never be true because you compare the value of the integer variable with a pointer to a string, and the chance of them being equal is slim to none.

---

For correct (as far as I can see) behavior try something like this

```
int ex;
scanf("%d", &ex);    // Read an integer directly into the variablke
printf("%d\n", ex);  // Print the integer as an integer
if (ex == 1)         // Compare the integer variable to an integer literal
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your code,

```
printf("%s\n", ex);
```

should be

```
printf("%d\n", ex);
```

then, `ex` being an `int`,

```
if (ex == "1")
```

should be

```
if (ex == 1)
```